# Is there an event that is fired when a discord channel is renamed?

Tags: python, discord.py

Can't find this anywhere, any help would be appreciated.

I have a really hacky method that works, but isn't efficient at all.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Steven! Could you include your 'really hacky method' as we need a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) of what you have tried, even if it's not the best code in the world. Stackoverflow isn't a code writing website. Happy coding!

Comment: Adding on to my previous comment, you can have a look at the discord.py documentation for some answers. There are events like [`channel_update`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html?highlight=channel%20update#discord.AuditLogAction.channel_update) and [`on_guild_channel_update`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html?highlight=channel%20update#discord.on_guild_channel_update) that may be of some use to you.

Answer (score 0):

The event fired is [`on_guild_channel_update`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html?highlight=channel%20update#discord.on_guild_channel_update). Note that this event also fires for updates like topic changes or permissions changes, not just renaming.

Example use:

```py
@bot.event
async def on_guild_channel_update(before, after):
    if before.name != after.name:
        # This update renamed the channel.
        print(f"On guild {before.guild.name} channel {before.name} was updated to {after.name}")
```

Output:

```py
On guild Achxy's server channel foo was updated to bar
```

Read more:
[`class discord.abc.GuildChannel`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html?highlight=channel%20update#discord.abc.GuildChannel)